# Getting response code 400 when trying to get access token from Azure AD

Tags: java, azure, https, azure-active-directory

I am implementing azure for my web application and trying to get access token by following there openId connect tutorial

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-protocols-oauth-code

And when i am requesting to get the access token, i am always getting bad request 400

Request to get access token :

> POST /{tenant}/oauth2/token HTTP/1.1
>
> Host: https://login.microsoftonline.com
>
> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
>
> grant_type=authorization_code
>
> &client_id=2d4d11a2-f814-46a7-890a-274a72a7309e
>
> &code=AwABAAAAvPM1KaPl.......
>
> &redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fmyapp%2F
>
> &resource=https%3A%2F%2Fservice.contoso.com%2F
>
> &client_secret=p@ssw0rd

here is my code :

```
public static String post( String endpoint,
        Map<String, String> params) {//YD
    StringBuffer paramString = new StringBuffer("");
    //if(!Utilities.checkInternetConnection(context)){
    //  return XMLHandler.getXMLForErrorCode(context, JSONHandler.ERROR_CODE_INTERNET_CONNECTION);
    //}
    Iterator<Entry<String, String>> iterator = params.entrySet().iterator();
    StringBuffer tempBuffer = new StringBuffer("");
    String paramval;
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        Entry<String, String> param = iterator.next();
        if (param != null) {
            if (paramString.length() > 0) {
                paramString.append("&");
            }
            System.out.println( "post key : " + param.getKey());
            String value;
            try {
                paramval = param.getValue();
                if(paramval!=null)
                    value = URLEncoder.encode(paramval, "UTF-8");
                else
                    value = "";
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                value = "";
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


                paramString.append(param.getKey()).append("=")
                        .append(value);
        }
    }
    try {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(endpoint);
        String data = "";

        try {
            // Add your data
            // httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs))
            //httppost.addHeader("Host", host);
            httppost.addHeader("Content-Type",
                    "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

            if (!paramString.equals("")) {
                if (tempBuffer.length() > 0) {
                    data = data + tempBuffer.toString();
                }
                data = data + paramString.toString();

                if (data.endsWith("&")) {
                    data = data.substring(0, data.length() - 1);
                } 

                httppost.setEntity(new ByteArrayEntity(data.getBytes()));
            }

            System.out.println( "post Stringbuffer  : " + data);

            // Execute HTTP Post Request
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            int statuscode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
            System.out.println("Response code : " + statuscode);
            if (statuscode != 200) {
                return null;
            }
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            InputStream in = null;
            if (entity != null) {
                in = entity.getContent();
            }

            if (in != null) {
                StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
                String line;
                try {
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                            new InputStreamReader(in, "UTF-8"));
                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        builder.append(line);
                    }
                } finally {
                    in.close();
                }

                String response2 = builder.toString();

                System.out.println("response :" + response2);
                retrycount = 0;

                return response2;
            }
        }
        catch(UnknownHostException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
        catch (EOFException eof) {
            if (retrycount < max_retry) {
                eof.printStackTrace();
                post( endpoint, params);
                retrycount = 1;
            }
        } catch (Throwable th) {
            throw new IOException("Error in posting :" + th.getMessage());
        }
        retrycount = 0;
        return null;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Please help me with this

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Is the client secret definitely the secret key that has been made for the app? It also needs to be URL-encoded.

Answer (score 0):

Have you ensured the redirect uri passed to /token is the same as the one you passed to /authorize

I believe, it will help if you can test the OAuth auth code flow with your current client id, secret and scope using Postman tool in order to rule out bad configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the code below to request `AuthorizationCode`.

```
public static void getAuthorizationCode() throws IOException {

        String encoding = "UTF-8";
        String params = "client_id=" + clientId 
                + "&response_type=" + reponseType
                + "&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fmyapp%2F"
                + "&response_mode=query"
                + "&resource=https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.windows.net"
                + "&state=12345";
        String path = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/" + tenantId + "/oauth2/authorize";
        byte[] data = params.getBytes(encoding);
        URL url = new URL(path);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", String.valueOf(data.length));
        conn.setConnectTimeout(5 * 1000);
        OutputStream outStream = conn.getOutputStream();
        outStream.write(data);
        outStream.flush();
        outStream.close();
        System.out.println(conn.getResponseCode());
        System.out.println(conn.getResponseMessage());

        BufferedReader br = null;
        if (conn.getResponseCode() != 200) {
            br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader((conn.getErrorStream())));
        } else {
            br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader((conn.getInputStream())));
        }
        System.out.println("Response body : " + br.readLine());
    }
```

Then you could get `access token` using the `AuthorizationCode` you got and get refresh code using the code below.

```
public static void getToken(String refreshToken) throws IOException {

        String encoding = "UTF-8";
        String params = "client_id=" + clientId + "&refresh_token=" + refreshToken
                + "&grant_type=refresh_token&resource=https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.windows.net";
        String path = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/" + tenantId + "/oauth2/token";
        byte[] data = params.getBytes(encoding);
        URL url = new URL(path);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", String.valueOf(data.length));
        conn.setConnectTimeout(5 * 1000);
        OutputStream outStream = conn.getOutputStream();
        outStream.write(data);
        outStream.flush();
        outStream.close();
        System.out.println(conn.getResponseCode());
        System.out.println(conn.getResponseMessage());

        BufferedReader br = null;
        if (conn.getResponseCode() != 200) {
            br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader((conn.getErrorStream())));
        } else {
            br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader((conn.getInputStream())));
        }
        System.out.println("Response body : " + br.readLine());
    }
```

Hope it helps you.